# Unable to move resized images to S3

Tags: php, image, amazon-s3, image-resizing

I want to upload my image in amazon s3 bucket .My original image upload successfully but thumbnail not uploaded. i referred some solution from stackflow .. nothing meet solution for this.. am uploading multiple images.. original images can upload successfully..

Here is my code i have tried

```
$fileCount = count($_FILES["image"]['name']);
            //echo $fileCount;
            for($i=0; $i < $fileCount; $i++)
            {
                $ImageName      = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]));
                $tmp = $_FILES["image"]["tmp_name"][$i];
                $actual_image_name = "slider".time().$ImageName;
                $new = "slider_new".time().$ImageName;
                //echo $actual_image_name."<br>";
                $data=array('slider_image'=>$NewImageName);             
                if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))
                {   
                    $targetFile ='http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$actual_image_name;
                    $image = new SimpleImage(); 
                    $image->load($targetFile);
                    $fileTempName=$image->resize(80,80); 
                    $image->save('http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/');
                        if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, $bucket , $new, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))
                        {
                        //insert query to database
                        }
                }

            }
```

Here is the class of resizing image

```
class SimpleImage {

   var $image;
   var $image_type;

   function load($filename) {

      $image_info = getimagesize($filename);
      $this->image_type = $image_info[2];
      if( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromjpeg($filename);
         // echo"jpg";

      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         $this->image = imagecreatefromgif($filename);
      } elseif( $this->image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {
        //echo"png";
         $this->image = imagecreatefrompng($filename);
      }
   }
   function save($filename, $image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG, $compression=75, $permissions=null) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image,$filename,$compression);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image,$filename);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image,$filename);
      }
      if( $permissions != null) {

         chmod($filename,$permissions);
      }
   }
   function output($image_type=IMAGETYPE_JPEG) {

      if( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_JPEG ) {
         imagejpeg($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_GIF ) {

         imagegif($this->image);
      } elseif( $image_type == IMAGETYPE_PNG ) {

         imagepng($this->image);
      }
   }
   function getWidth() {

      return imagesx($this->image);
   }
   function getHeight() {

      return imagesy($this->image);
   }
   function resizeToHeight($height) {

      $ratio = $height / $this->getHeight();
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resizeToWidth($width) {
      $ratio = $width / $this->getWidth();
      $height = $this->getheight() * $ratio;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function scale($scale) {
      $width = $this->getWidth() * $scale/100;
      $height = $this->getheight() * $scale/100;
      $this->resize($width,$height);
   }

   function resize($width,$height) {
      $new_image = imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
      imagecopyresampled($new_image, $this->image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $width, $height, $this->getWidth(), $this->getHeight());
      $this->image = $new_image;
      echo $this->image;
   }      

}
```

Comment: `$image->save('http://'.$bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/');` What is this line supposed to do?

Comment: am new to aws .. when we resize and move to a folder we normally give the path in the save method.. i tried to give s3 bath there.. correct me if i did wrong.. i am really unaware of s3

Comment: i also used resize class for this.. when am doing that in to a folder it is happening.. here is my code   for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['rooms']);$i++)
{
$new_filename=rand().time().$photos[$i];
$form_data=array('photos'=>$new_filename,'project_rooms'=>$rooms[$i]); 
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photos']['tmp_name'][$i],"../uploads/projects/".$new_filename))
{
$resizeObj = new resize("../uploads/projects/".$new_filename); 
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(278, 339, 'crop'); 
$resizeObj -> saveImage("../uploads/projects/medium/".$new_filename, 100); 
$resizeObj -> resizeImage(374,164, 'crop');  
}  
 }

Comment: What is the value of `$fileNameTemp` immediately before `if($s3->putObjectFile($fileTempName, ...`?  I don't see how that value gets set.

Comment: @michael leave my that code.. can you help me to guide what i have to do after        if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))
                {

Comment: I believe I may have been unclear with my previous question, which also contained an error on my part.  What does `$fileNameTemp` contain?  Have you verified that it has the expected value?

Comment: not actually.. i was tried to store resized image in $fileNameTemp  and tried to put that in to s3 bucket.. so that i used that code.. dont refer that code..upto here it is correct. so i can upload original image.. inside that scope everything i tried was not correct.. can you help me to do        
                if($s3->putObjectFile($tmp, $bucket , $actual_image_name, S3::ACL_PUBLIC_READ))
                { }

Comment: @michael.. can you help me to solve this